# Prediction at means of a subsample in R

Tags: r, predict

Here's my code:

```
install.packages("wooldridge")
library(wooldridge)
data(wage1)
wage1reg<-lm(lwage ~ educ + exper + tenure, data = wage1)
```

I am trying to predict fitted values for these three variables at their means. What is the correct code? 
These things do not work:

```
wagemeans<-data.frame(c(colMeans(data.frame(wage1$educ, wage1$exper, wage1$tenure))))
predict(wage1reg, newdata=wagemeans)
```

Also, if I try something else, like

```
wage1.subset1.means<-data.frame(colMeans(subset(wage1, select=c(educ, exper, tenure))))
predict(wage1reg, newdata=wage1.subset1.means)
```

It doesn't work either.

What is the best way to find predicted values for means of three variables?

Answer (score 0):

The wagemeans dataframe is not in the proper format for predict(). 
Use this instead

```r
library(wooldridge)
data(wage1)

wage1reg<-lm(lwage ~ educ + exper + tenure, data = wage1) 

wagemeans<-data.frame(educ=mean(wage1$educ),exper=mean(wage1$exper),tenure=mean(wage1$tenure))

predict(wage1reg,newdata = wagemeans)

#output
#     1 
# 1.623268
```

For more than three columns it will be easier to use the `dplyr` package

```r
library(wooldridge)
data(wage1)

wage1reg<-lm(lwage ~ educ + exper + tenure, data = wage1) 

library(dplyr)

wagemeans <- wage1 %>% 
  summarise_at(colnames(wage1[,2:4]),mean,na.rm=TRUE)

predict(wage1reg,newdata = wagemeans)
```

All you will need to do is to edit the `lm()` to include the new variables and the column numbers (currently 2:4).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

Is there any other way to get the names right if I have, say, 100 variables (dummies, interaction terms, etc.), some of which were created "on the fly"?

Comment: If the other variables are columns in the dataframe (or can be made into columns like a^2, a*b, etc.), it is possible and I have edited my answer to include how to do that.